# Format SQL Query Results Into EMail Body (SMTP) C# Console app

Tags: c#, sql, console-application

Good morning Stack Overflow, I am trying to figure out how to format SQL query results into an email body. There are a few catches however- I am using App.config connection strings and although I am only referencing one server, I need to reference 7 different databases. To make matters more confusing, I will be running the same query on all 7 DBs and would like to combine the results into a nice little table in the body of the email. I am using a class library to send the emails so I pretty much have everything figured out except how to query all 7 dbs and combine the data into the same table.

I am using SMTP and this is a console app.

Please note that this is my first question i have ever posted on stack and i have thoroughly researched this. I know it sayd to post code but I dont really have any code written for it yet. I just need a place to start! I am much more experienced in SQL than i am in C# so if this is a basic problem I apologize. If you need more information regarding my question please let me know!

Comment: so are you able to work out result set from all 7 db's into a table and create an email from sql ?

Comment: No that is what my goal is- The connection strings work and i just dont know how to combine all the result sets

Comment: Are you on SQL Server and .Net Framework? Winforms/Webforms/MVC/NetCore?

Comment: Yes - SQL Server .net Framework.

Comment: Do you query each database from your C# console? Or you query all databases from your SQL Server and return a single resultset to your app? Stored procedure/View/Function for example.

Comment: Check my answer below please.

Comment: This is so Helpful Santiago! I didn't even think to union the queries and that is a great idea. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please upvote or mark as accepeted answer if it helped to solve your problem.

Comment: @SantiagoTrejo, First off, you're the man. I had no experience in HTML so this was really helpful. I used your idea of a union and for formatting purposes, i elected to do a variation of what you originally suggested- I created separate CTE tables for all 7 dbs and lined it up more nicely however when i send the email, there are no boarders (as expected) and also the dates i pull though have the following format= mm/dd/yyyy 00:00:00. How do i get rid of the time? and if possible, how do i put in boarders to separate cells? Once again, your'e the man!

Comment: Hey @mathew paton! Check my answer update.

Comment: Hey @SantiagoTrejo, I may be brain dead but I am not seeing an update. I am also new to stack so i may not be looking in the right place hahaha. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks again man!

Comment: Your Update is super helpful but I am still a little off. The results I get from my query is 2 columns per db so 14 columns in all. column 1 iwll always be a number and column 2 will always be the date that i cannot seem to format. It alternates by db (I made 7 CTEs and full joined them to line up side by side) where would i Put Date.Parse(yourDateField).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); in the code below? the intellisense wont even recognize the DATE method (it wants to give me datetime). Once again I have thoroughly researched this I am still just so new to HTML and C# I am virtually useless> Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah `DateTime` is ok, I posted `Date` because VB is my main language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I supposed that you'll be querying all 7 databases from your SQL Server, and since you're strong on SQL I created a dummy stored procedure from where all 7 queries would be union/joined:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE QueryAllDatabases 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    -- Added some dummy parameters here for future use in your queries.
    @active bit,
    @birthdate date
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    -- QUERY DATABASE-1
    SELECT
        'Hulk Hogan' Name,
        'hh@email.com' Email
    --FROM
        -- DATABASE1.dbo.YourTable
    WHERE
        @active = 1 AND  -- "1" passed from console app.
        @birthdate > '2018-01-01'  -- "2018-05-29" passed from console app.

    UNION ALL

    -- QUERY DATABASE-2
    SELECT
        'Chum Lee' Name,
        'chum@email.com' Email
    --FROM
        -- DATABASE2.dbo.YourTable
    WHERE
        @active = 1 AND
        @birthdate > '2018-01-01'
END
GO
```

Now here comes the C# console app part, where it will obtain all the 7 database queries from a single stored procedure call:

**Program.cs** (This is a C# Console solution)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp_C_Sharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessData();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Query the database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static DataSet QueryDatabase() 
        {
            // Credentials to your database.
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SERVER-NAME;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=user;Password=yourpassword");

            // Name of the stored procedure to be excecuted and connection to database.
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("QueryAllDatabases", connection);

            // DataSet to store the query results.
            DataSet result = new DataSet();

            // To excecute and fill the dataset.
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            // Set the sqlcommand to "Stored Procedure".
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Pass some parameters to your database's Stored Procedure if you need to.
            // We're sending some quick dummy params here.
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("active", "1");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("birthdate", "2018-05-29");

            // Open connection to database.
            connection.Open();
            // Execute the stored procedure and fill the dataset.
            da.Fill(result);
            // Close the connection.
            connection.Close();

            // Object disposal.
            da.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Dispose();

            // Return the query results.
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Construct the message body and send it by smpt mail.
        /// </summary>
        static void ProcessData()
        {
            // Store the query results.
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            // StringBuilder to construct your HTML table.
            StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();

            // Get data from database;
            ds = QueryDatabase();

            // If records available:
            if( ds.Tables.Count > 0 )
            {
                // Start table's header construct.
                table.Append("<table><thead><tr>");

                // Iterate through each column to insert the column name in the custom table.
                foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
                {
                    table.Append("<td>" + col.ColumnName + "</td>");                    
                }

                // End header construct.
                table.Append("</tr></thead>");
            }

            // Now, iterate the database records.
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows )
            {
                // Insert one TR per row.
                table.Append("<tr>");
                foreach(DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
                {
                    // Insert each data column into a TD cell.
                    table.Append("<td>");
                    table.Append(row[dc.ColumnName]);
                    table.Append("</td>");
                }
                // Close the table row and goto next record if available or exit loop.
                table.Append("</tr>");
            }

            // All records inserted. Close the table.
            table.Append("</table>");

            // Dsiplay the table in console.
            Console.WriteLine(table.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();

            /*
             * 
             * From here you could send "table.ToString()" as the "Body" parameter to your SMTP mail library.
             * 
             * */
        }
    }
}
```

At the end you will obtain a `table.ToString()` where your custom table is stored with all the 7 database queries joinen and HTML formated. So, you can send this string as a parameter to your SMTP Mail library.

Some screenshoots to see the results:

[image: Console]
[image: HTML code copied-pasted from Console to text editor, and manually formated to make it legible.]
[image: HTML result viewed in browser]

**UPDATE:**

For the border you must apply some styling directly to the table elements, I haven't found a way to include a CSS file when building emails:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: lavender">
      <td style="border: 1px solid blue">Name<td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid blue">Name<td>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style.asp

As for the date, you could format it from your SQL script:

```
SELECT
    CAST(myDate as DATE)
FROM
  ...
```

Or directly in the C# code:

```
Date.Parse(yourDateField).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: I may have to do it in C# because i used a convert function in SQL but it still shows time. Strange haha. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You are messing several things into one.

For starters: SMTP is a transport protocol and does not matters for your task. 
What matters is format of content of your email-messages. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Type

After that: Can you send multipart messages? Can you create attaches to emails? Or you limited to text(html) messages?

> so I pretty much have everything figured out except how to query all 7 dbs

Maybe you don't need to program anything for this task.

But it depends on what OS you using and which DBs you need to query.

**Case 1**: excel file with 7 connection strings and 7 lists (I did so near to 10 years ago)

**Case 2**: you have (can get) access to BI system and many of them have feature for scheduling reports (this is too case

**Case 3**: users of reports does not need rich BI graphics and waiting only for csv-files and afterwards they can process data themselves. You need to find dump-tool for you db and write a bash/cmd script to automate it and send multipart with attachments.

**Case 4**: Everything like in Case 3 but you can save results to network share/ftp/sftp/google docs/other and send only http-links.

Clarify your requirements and look for tools available for you. 
Try to do something with them.

If you encounter new problem - return to SO with new questions.

Good luck!